# How to kick someone out of a google drive file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm working on a file and I need to share it with a google group. There is also a fairly small amount people in that group who I do not want on this file at all maybe about 50.

I was wondering if there is any way to completely kick someone out a google drive file using the drive api?

Comment: Do you want to do it with apps-script? Because if not you can create another group or give permission one by one.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to block someone that is member of a group which the file is shared to.

One alternative is to create another group, just with the people that you want to be able to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the capability to create shared drives you you can invite only the people you want to have access and place the file that you wish to share in the shared drive.

[Shared Drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-shareddrives)